# Set an attribute/value of a custom Complex Type

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created a my own ComplexType - Transaction.

I would like to set an attribute of that complex type by default from the calling element.

For example:

```
<xs:complexType name="TransactionType">
  <xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed ="N" maxOccurs ="1" />
    <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1" />
  </xs:all>
  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Transaction" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Debit" type="TransactionType" />
      <xs:element name="Credit" type="TransactionType" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

For Debit i would like to have a fixed value TransactionType.Type = "D", and for the Credit element i would like it to be transactionType.Type = "C"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want can't be done the way you've phrased it. I'll show a different way, just to illustrate a possibility.

No matter what, you have to use new types.

For the first approach, the assumption is that you want all the particles and the attribute in the base type, as opposed to particles without the attribute (for the latter the solution would be a more "elegant" use of extension instead of restriction). As to why the restriction is not that helpful here, should be easy to understand after looking at the XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSR Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="TransactionType">
        <xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed ="N" maxOccurs ="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>   
    <xs:complexType name="DebitTransactionType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="TransactionType">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed ="N" maxOccurs ="1"/>
                    <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>                 
                </xs:all>
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="D"/>                  
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CreditTransactionType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="TransactionType">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed ="N" maxOccurs ="1"/>
                    <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>                 
                </xs:all>
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="C"/>                  
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>   
    <xs:element name="Transaction">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Debit" type="DebitTransactionType"/>
                <xs:element name="Credit" type="CreditTransactionType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<Transaction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <Debit type="D">
        <Amount>1</Amount>
        <Status>N</Status>
    </Debit>
    <Credit type="C">
        <Amount>1</Amount>
        <Status>N</Status>
    </Credit>
</Transaction>
```

The thing with restriction is that you have to "repeat" the whole set... some would say not that elegant.

Another approach, if you can remove the attribute from the base type, is to use extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSR Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="TransactionType">
        <xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed ="N" maxOccurs ="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs ="1"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>   
    <xs:complexType name="DebitTransactionType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="TransactionType">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="D"/>                  
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CreditTransactionType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="TransactionType">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="C"/>                  
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>   
    <xs:element name="Transaction">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Debit" type="DebitTransactionType"/>
                <xs:element name="Credit" type="CreditTransactionType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It seems you have some redundance since you have the attribute's value fixed, and tied to the name of the element... If it is not a hard requirement, I would remove the attribute...